# ¿Cómo hago para reiniciar una function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

recientemente comencé a programar por lo que perdonen si mi terminología no es la correcta. Empecé a trabajar sobre un juego de Space Invader y tuve un problema con la función de Game Over y su botón de reinicio. Tengo entendido que si pregunto con un if si quiero reiniciar el juego y pongo que si (para que se reinicie de 0) solo tengo que hacer la llamada a la función del juego (algo así como SpaceInvader() ) y debería funcionar. Pero lo que ocurre es que el juego se reinicia por encima de la partida anterior y quería saber que necesito hacer/cambiar para solucionarlo.

Les dejo el código:

```py
def boton(mensaje,posx,posy,ancho,alto,ColorA,ColorDis,accion=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if posx+ancho > mouse[0] > posx and posy+alto > mouse[1] > posy:
         pygame.draw.rect(ventana,ColorA,(posx,posy,ancho,alto))
         if click[0] == 1 and accion != None:
            accion()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(ventana,ColorDis,(posx,posy,ancho,alto))

    miniTexto = pygame.font.Font("prisma/Prisma.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = textos(mensaje, miniTexto)
    textRect.center = ( (posx+(ancho/2)), (posy+(alto/2)) )
    ventana.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Esta es la función *Game Over*:

```py
def gameOver():
    if Perdiste==True:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
        ventana.blit(ImagenFondo,(0,0))
        miFuente2 = pygame.font.Font("prisma/Prisma.ttf",70)
        Texto2 = miFuente2.render("Game Over",0,(green))
        ventana.blit(Texto2,(240,170))

        boton("Inicio",275,320,150,50,bright_green,green,SpaceInvader)
        boton("Cerrar",500,320,150,50,bright_red,red,quit)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Este es el código principal:

```
def SpaceInvader():
    global pausa
    pausa

    global puntos
    puntos = 0

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")

    pygame.mixer.music.load("Musica/Tha Aphex Twin.mp3") #Musica
    pygame.mixer.music.play(3)

    miFuenteSistema = pygame.font.Font("prisma/Prisma.ttf",40)
    Texto = miFuenteSistema.render("Fin del juego",0,(green))

    jugador = Nave.nave_espacial(ancho,alto)
    cargarEnemigos()


    enJuego = True #Sirve para determinar si el jugador esta vivo, en este caso el juego sigue en progreso

    reloj =pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:

        reloj.tick(60)


        tiempo = pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if enJuego==True:

                if evento.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[K_LEFT]:
                        jugador.movimientoIzquierda()

                    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
                        jugador.movimientoDerecha()

                    if evento.key ==pygame.K_p:
                        pausa = True
                        pausa1()

                    elif evento.key ==K_SPACE:
                        x,y = jugador.rect.center
                        jugador.disparar(x,y)

        ventana.blit(ImagenFondo,(0,0))
        score(puntos)

        jugador.dibujar(ventana) #Aca imprime por pantalla los objetos

        if len(jugador.lista_disparos)>0:
            for x in jugador.lista_disparos:
                x.dibujar(ventana)
                x.Trayectoria()
                if x.rect.top<-10:
                    jugador.lista_disparos.remove(x)
                else:
                    for enemigo in listaEnemigo:
                         if x.rect.colliderect(enemigo.rect):
                            listaEnemigo.remove(enemigo)
                            jugador.lista_disparos.remove(x)
                            global puntos
                            puntos = puntos+100

        if len(listaEnemigo)>0:
            for enemigo in listaEnemigo:
                enemigo.comportamiento(tiempo)
                enemigo.dibujar(ventana)

                if enemigo.rect.colliderect(jugador.rect):
                    jugador.destruccion()
                    enJuego = False
                    detenerTodo()

                if len(enemigo.lista_disparos)>0:
                    for x in enemigo.lista_disparos:
                        x.dibujar(ventana)
                        x.Trayectoria()
                        if x.rect.colliderect(jugador.rect):
                            jugador.destruccion()
                            enJuego = False
                            detenerTodo()

                        if x.rect.top>900:
                            enemigo.lista_disparos.remove(x)
                        else:
                            for disparo in jugador.lista_disparos:
                                if x.rect.colliderect(disparo.rect):
                                    jugador.lista_disparos.remove(disparo)
                                    enemigo.lista_disparos.remove(x)

        if enJuego==False:
            pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(3000) #La musica se atenue por 3 segundos y luego se detenga
            ventana.blit(Texto,(290,170))
            global Perdiste
            Perdiste = True
            gameOver()

        pygame.display.update()

introJuego() 
SpaceInvader()
```

Si necesitan todo les dejo el link completo:
https://pastebin.com/u6hpKzLQ

y el de las imágenes:
https://github.com/codigofacilito/imagenes_pygame

Comment: Cuando dices que reinicia por encima, ¿te refieres a que no borra la partida anterior?. De todos modos, usar variables globales tiene el problema de que no controlas quién las modifica. Todas las inicializaciones de las variables globales que has puesto al inicio del código (el que se ve en pastebin) deberías meterlas en una función de inicio y llamarla cuando quieras reiniciar.

Comment: Exacto, no borra el anterior